# How to create a login screen with changing background images?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a login page. As per the wireframes, there are images in the background and they change in every few seconds.

Consider it like a splash screen with a login form. I have developed the login form. But the splash screen is the issue.

How do I achieve this with react.js?

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Some source images loaded up in the component, when the component mounts, set a background image and an interval timer to swap out the source. Feel free to provide a snippet of your code you've tried.

Comment: @drewReese can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist is to setup a background image container (likely taking 100% of the view height and width) with the following CSS:

```
// keep image from scrolling when content is scrollable
background-attachment: fixed;
// center the image within the container
background-position: center;
// scale the image to cover the container the smaller quantity of width or height
background-size: cover;

width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Then in code choose your flavor of CSS-in-JS. I like `styled-components`, but for brevity I'll use an in-line `style` attribute:

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${/* pass reference to image */})` }}
```

Sample Component:

```
import bgImgArray from './assets/img';

function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => setIndex(i => i + 1), 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  const bgImg = bgImgArray[index % bgImgArray.length];

  return (
    <div
      className="App backgroundContainer"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg})`
      }}
    >
      /* container content, children, etc.. */
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dynamic-background-img-container]

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. but for some reason, the images aren't changing for me. any suggestions?

Comment: @NaumanTanwir Do you have your code up somewhere I can take a peek at it? Link here?

Comment: I am doing exactly the same way you've done in the sandbox. basically, only the first img in the array is loading.

Comment: @NaumanTanwir It may be just some small silly mistake, but without seeing your code it's hard to tell, it could be nearly *anything*. Are there any errors in the console? Things I would look at are making sure I have a valid computed image array index and if state is updating as expected. It's silly, but check that your array has more than a single image in it. Not many moving parts here. Can you copy exactly what you have into another sandbox?

Comment: the problem is with the timer. it's not incrementing.